# Multiple selection in RoR form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, form-for, multiple-select

I have a list of items that I want to have as options for a variable.  They will be saved in the model as an array, and are to be displayed as a list in the form_for.  I was using

```
f.select(:var_name, [["option1"],["option2"],["option3"]], {}, {multiple: "multiple"})
```

Which works great to save into the model.
But when going back to the form, nothing is selected (even if the variable has them all saved). Then if I submit the form again, it passes an empty array. The only way for it to save correctly is to re-select the ones I want every time I view the form.
How can I get them to pass into the multi-select box?

Comment: After doing some more looking, I think it needs :selected => 'something'
But I'm not sure what to put in there??

Comment: Can you provide the whole code for your form?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem stems from your `choices` parameter. You probably need an array of [option,id] mappings:

```
f.select(:person_id, Person.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {}, { :multiple => true })
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but it's working now, and didn't need the option,id arry.

Answer (score 0):

When I started working on it again today, it was working.  I'm not sure what change was made, but it could be that I needed to restart the server.  It still looks like

```
f.select(:name, [[" "],["option"],["option2"],["option3"]], {}, {:multiple => true})
```

So it must not have been this code.  In addition, the form beginning looks like

```
form_for(@model_name) do |f|
```

which hasn't changed either.

Regardless, it works now. Thanks!